# Helm value from template

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'd like my Helm chart to use different image repository depending on cloud provider (AWS vs. Aliyun) unfortunately I am getting the following error when trying to run `helm package` command:

```
Error: cannot load values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"tpl (.Files.Get \"config/repository.config\") . | quote":interface {}(nil)}
```

In my `values.yaml`
I have:

```
configuration:
  system:
    mode:
      cloud_provider: aws

image:
repository: {{ tpl (.Files.Get "config/repository.config") . | quote }}
```

in my `config/repository.config` file I have:

```
{{- if eq ( include "cloud_provider" . | trim ) "aliyun" -}}
    registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/x/kube-state-metrics
{{- end -}}
{{- if eq ( include "cloud_provider" . | trim ) "aws" -}}
    k8s.gcr.io/kube-state-metrics/kube-state-metrics
{{- end -}}
```

in `templates/_helpers.tpl` file I've added:

```
{{- define "cloud_provider" -}}
    {{ required "Cloud provider required at .Values.configuration.system.mode.cloud_provider due to Google to unreachable in China" .Values.configuration.system.mode.cloud_provider }}
    {{ $valid_cloud_provider := list "aws" "aliyun" }}
    {{- if not (has .Values.configuration.system.mode.cloud_provider $valid_cloud_provider ) -}}
        {{ fail "Invalid cloud provider set. Should be aws or aliyun" }}
    {{end}}
    {{- else -}}
        {{ .Values.configuration.system.mode.cloud_provider | default "disabled" }}
    {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution for the error but an alternative approach. I hope this also could help:

I won't put such expressions in the values file `values.yaml`

```
repository: {{ tpl (.Files.Get "config/repository.config") . | quote }}
```

I would use instead different yaml files for each environment:

Add a `aliyun.yaml` values file

```
registry: registry.cn-qingdao.aliyuncs.com/x/kube-state-metrics
```

And call helm with this values file

```
helm ... -f aliyun.yaml
```